# Error when trying to use @angular/material in Stackblitz

Tags: angular-material

On stackblitz, when trying to add import to Angular Material , like this:

`import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';`

This is the error:

File '/turbo_modules/@angular/material@12.0.1/index.d.ts' is not a module.

Here link to stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-11rird?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added like this

```
import {  MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
```

Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In the project on stackblitz, he also cursed at material.
As it turned out, it does not install dependencies correctly.
Working option:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```